# Opening, calculating, closing MS Excel spreadsheet without Excel installed [EPPlus]

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library to create spreadsheets (reports). In my app every new document first opens an older report to get previous results. The problem is when getting data from cells containing formulas - [unfortunately EPPlus doesn't have a calculating engine](http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/241913). To make it work I need to open the old report in Excel, save changes (formulas are calculated), and then new report is created properly. If i don't do it, then the values from formula-cells are blank.

1. Is there a way to simulate (not doing it manually, but with code)
   opening, calculating, closing an excel spreadsheet without excel
   installed?
2. Any ideas how to workaround it?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on any machines? If so, you might consider using Excel services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163374.aspx

Comment: That's it, I need to do this on server side without Excel installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPPlus can calculate formulas from version 4. See this page - https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

OpenXML is what I used when I didn't have access to Office.... you can build office documents using it without having Office on your machine.... For me there was a learning curve and a lot of googling to figure things out.

I still don't know all of the ins and outs of it, but it worked for what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. *"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."* ...but at the same time they give a lot of [useful links on OpenXML manipulation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) - worth visiting.
2. http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/ - but it's very expensive, $999/subscription
3. [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) (a C# port of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) -  the Java API for Microsoft Documents). The Java version [can read calculated values](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html), so maybe C# version also could.
4. [Office Integration Pack](http://officeintegration.codeplex.com/) - don't know if it can calculate